# What is the Joomla database code for the group_concat from tables joined by a third

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

I am looking to group_concat the results from the fields from multiple rows where there is a an intermediate table

'#__ext_resources'

```
a.id a.title
1    Blaa
2    Blee 
3    Blii
```

Joining table
'#__ext_resource_categories'

```
rc.resource_id rc.category_id
1               1
1               2
2               2
3               3
```

Table whose title field needs concatenating
'#__categories'

```
c.id c.title
1    category boo
2    category foo
3    category noo
```

So the query I have created will give resource fields plus categories plus the category id

```
 a.id a.title category_id c.title
 1     Blaa   1,2         boo, foo
 2     Blee   2           foo  
 3     Blii   3           noo
```

The following works as MySQL

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rc.category_id) category_ids,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.title) categories,

FROM db_ext_resources a
LEFT JOIN db_ext_resources_categories   rc  ON a.id                 = rc.resource_id
LEFT JOIN db_categories                           c   ON rc.category_id       = c.id
```

WHERE a.id = 192

But what is the Joomla code please?
The following works - with no intermediate joining table

```
$db = $this->getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('a.*')
->select('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rc.category_id  SEPARATOR ", ") category_ids 
          FROM #__ext_resources_categories  WHERE resource_id = a.id) category_ids')
->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__ext_resources_categories',  'rc') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id')                . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('rc.resource_id') . ')')
                                ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__categories',                          'c') .  ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('rc.category_id')      . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('c.id') . ')')
```

**BUT** 
if I put

```
->select('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.title SEPARATOR ", ")        categories WHERE rc.resource_id = a.id AND c.id = rc.category_id) categories')
```

in there or numerous variants it doesn't seem to work
nor

```
->select('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.title SEPARATOR ", ") categories FROM #__categories LEFT JOIN  '.$db->quoteName("#__dbsupportplus_resources_categories",  "rc").' ON a.id = rc.resource_id AND rc.category_id = c.id) categories')
```

I have tried putting the whole MySQL statement into a $query->select('(".$var.")')

To no avail. Any suggestions please?

Comment: If your question is resolved, please award the green tick to one of the answers below so that this page is deemed resolved in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Finally did it sticking everything inside a ->select

```
$MySQL = all the rest of the raw mysql query including the GROUP_CONCAT, FROM, LEFT JOIN statements
$query->select('a.*')
      ->select($mysql);
```

But if anyone has a way that uses the Joomla code it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This would be the easiest method of running an query of this type. Joomla is still lacking query methods for database interaction such as group_concat, subqueries, etc. Maybe one day we will have those. For now the method you are using will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Joomla method-based version of your working mysql:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select(
                array(
                    "A.id",
                    "A.name",
                    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.category_id) category_ids",
                    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.title) categories"
                )
            )
            ->from("db_ext_resources A")
            ->leftJoin("db_ext_resources_categories B ON A.id = B.resource_id")
            ->leftJoin("db_categories C ON B.category_id = C.id")
            ->where("A.id = 192");
```

I am using an array in the `select()` call to minimize code "width".  I am not calling `qn()` because none of the tablenames or columns require it.  If the `192` is actually a variable, be sure to cast it as an integer with `(int)` for security reasons.

This is what `$query->dump()` will produce:

```
SELECT A.id,A.name,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.category_id) category_ids,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.title) categories
FROM db_ext_resources A
LEFT JOIN db_ext_resources_categories B ON A.id = B.resource_id
LEFT JOIN db_categories C ON B.category_id = C.id
WHERE A.id = 192
```